# Does Mars' "Northern ocean" have another name? What about the "Inland Sea"?

Tags: mars, water, naming, planetary-science

The March 15, 2019 Phys.org article [A NASA spacecraft may have explored the edges of an early Mars sea in 1997](https://phys.org/news/2019-03-nasa-spacecraft-explored-edges-early.html) shows a stylized map of an area on Mars where the [Mars Pathfinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Pathfinder) landed and uses colors to indicate where bodies of surface water might have once existed.

They are labeled as

- Northern ocean
- Inland Sea

and I noticed they are capitalized. Do these reflect proper nouns and names of possible bodies of water that are recognized by planetary scientists or Martian cartographers (or should I have said Mars cartographers?)? Do these possible bodies of water have other names as well?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the Wikipedia article on the [Mars ocean hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_ocean_hypothesis), the ocean is sometimes called the Paleo-Ocean, and sometimes called "Oceanus Borealis" (a.k.a. "Northern Ocean" for those who feel that *quidquid Latine dictum sit, altum videtur.*)

The inland sea in the article is located in the Simud Interior Basin (part of the Simud Valles). The *Nature* article describing the findings ([Rodriguez et al. 2019](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-39632-1)) doesn't appear to give the sea a name, although it does use the term "SIB sea" at one point.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed in the Nature article the term "Late Hesperian northern ocean". Would that count as a name?

Comment: @uhoh - "Late Hesperian" refers to a period of the Martian geological history. I'd say that term works in much the same way as "Cretaceous North America" - not really a separate name.